# Can we approximate any eigenvalue of an infinite matrix via eigenvalues of some sequence of submatrices which approximates the matrix?

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, approximation-theory, infinite-matrices

Let $T:\ell^2\to\ell^2$ be a compact linear operator. Let $[T]=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ be the representing infinite matrix of $T$ with respect to the canonical base. Let $T_n$ be the finite rank operator defined by the matrix $(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^{n}$ embedded into an infinite matrix. Thus $T_n\to T$ in norm.

Can we approximate the eigenvalues of $T$ with eigenvalues of $T_n$?

Comment: If you diagonalize the operator $T$ per the spectral theorem, it seems like the eigenvalues would match up precisely.

Comment: You are right @Chris, I guess I am interested in the case when $T$ is not diagonalizable. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I by chance came across Chapter XI.9 of the Dunford & Schwartz classic ["Linear operators. Part II. Spectral theory"](https://books.google.de/books/about/Linear_Operators_Spectral_theory.html?id=kuVQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), and Lemma 5 in said chapter reads as follows:

> Let $T_n,T$ be compact operators, and let $T_n\to T$ in the uniform operator topology. Let $\lambda_m(T)$ be an enumeration of the non-zero eigenvalues of $T$, each repeated according to its multiplicity. Then there exist enumerations $\lambda_m(T_n)$ of the non-zero eigenvalues of $T_n$, with repetitions according to multiplicity, such that
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_m(T_n)=\lambda_m(T),\qquad m\geq 1,
> $$
>   the limit being uniform in $m$.

As you correctly observed the finite truncations $T_n$ converge to $T$ in norm ${}^1$ so the eigenvalue approximation property you were interested in holds.

---

<sub>${}^1$: For anyone who wants to see why that is: in separable Hilbert spaces, such as $\ell^2$, finite-dimensional projections $\Pi_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle e_i,\cdot\rangle e_i$ converge to the identity in the strong operator topology (simple consequence of [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality)) so compactness of $T$ ensures $T_n=\Pi_nT\Pi_n\to T$ in norm (see, e.g., Proposition 2.1 in [this article by Widom](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870876901134)).</sub>

Comment: Also I will leave my old answer (from March 6th, 2019) up & unedited as it is fundamentally different from this one and also contains some neat facts about compact (tringular) operators which sometimes come in handy.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a full answer but maybe an idea or a rough roadmap on how to approach this problem (and also it's too long for a comment).

First consider $T\in\mathcal K(\ell_2)$ (compact linear operator on $\ell_2$) where $T$ is triangular, i.e. there exists an orthonormal basis $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $\ell_2$ such that the infinite matrix $T_g:=(\langle g_j,Tg_k\rangle)_{j,k\in\mathbb N}$ is either [upper or lower triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix). For such an operator, it is known that the non-zero eigenvalues of $T$ are exactly the diagonal entries of $T_g$. More precisely,
$$
\sigma(T)\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace = \lbrace \langle g_j,Tg_j\rangle\,|\,j\in\mathbb N\rbrace\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace
$$
refer to Theorem A.7 in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/10.1080/03081087.2018.1515884) (or Thm.4.2 in the respective [arXiv-version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01023)). W.l.o.g. let $T$ be upper triangular. Now if one defines
$$
T_{g,n}=\sum\nolimits_{a,b=1}^n\langle g_a,Tg_b\rangle\langle g_b,\cdot\rangle g_a=\begin{pmatrix} \langle g_1,Tg_1\rangle&\cdots&\cdots&\langle g_1,Tg_n\rangle\\0 &\ddots&&\vdots\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&\cdots&0&\langle g_n,Tg_n\rangle\end{pmatrix}\oplus 0
$$
as the embedded upper left $n\times n$ block of $T$ **w.r.t. the basis in which $T$ is triangular** then, evidently, the eigenvalues of $T_{g,n}$ converge to the eigenvalues of $T$ in the sense that the eigenvalue sequence $\lambda_{g,n}$ (of $T_{g,n}$) converges to the eigenvalue sequence $\lambda$ (of $T$) in the $\ell^\infty$-norm.

> **Problem 1.** Does this statement still hold for triangular $T\in\mathcal K(\ell_2)$ if $T_{g,n}$ is replaced by the block approximation $T_{f,n}$ with respect to an arbitrary orthonormal basis $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $\ell_2$?

Unlike in finite dimensions, there is no Schur triangulation for arbitrary operators if the underlying Hilbert space is infinite-dimensional (not even for compact operators). However, one still has the following similar result, cf. Lemma 16.28 in ["Introduction to Functional Analysis"](https://books.google.de/books?id=FavCGyUirRkC&dq=meise+vogt+introduction+to+functional+analysis) by Meise & Vogt (1997):

For $T\in\mathcal K(\ell_2)$ there exists an orthogonal decomposition $\ell_2=\mathcal H_0\oplus \mathcal H_1$ and an orthonormal basis $(g_j)_{j\in M}$ of $\mathcal H_0$ (where $M$ can be finite or infinite and corresponds to the non-zero eigenvalues of $T$) such that, roughly speaking,
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix} T_{0,0}&T_{0,1}\\0&T_{1,1}\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$ 
Here, $T_{0,0}$ is upper triangular w.r.t. $(g_j)_{j\in M}$ and $\sigma(T_{1,1})=\lbrace 0\rbrace$.

> **Problem 2.** Is this construction / this idea enough to extend the above result to arbitrary compact operators (*"There exists an orthonormal basis of $\ell_2$ such that the eigenvalue sequence of ..."*)?

This might boil down to the question on if and how one can control the eigenvalues when taking out blocks from the Volterra part $T_{1,1}$ of $T$. Similar to Problem 1, the following question arises naturally:

> **Problem 3.** If Problem 2 has a positive answer, does it even hold for any orthonormal basis of $\ell_2$?

Answer (score 2):

I can't really *answer* this, but I have an observation/analysis which convinced me, that in the following example the eigenvalues of an infinite matrix (matrix-operator) are (should be) complex, but the eigenvalues of all truncated matrixes with arbitrary truncation-size are always real and some of them growing to infinity by increasing the truncation-size. *Perhaps the answer of @FrederikVomEnde and especially his references contains everything needed here, but I'm not expert enough to judge this. In this case take my answer just as an illustration by a nontrivial example*.

---

This seems to be the case for "Carleman-matrices" for the function $f(x)=b^x$ with $b \gt \exp(\exp(-1)) $ *(in the discussions in the tetration-forum this number is often called  $\eta$)*

There is a conjugacy-operation, which for finite matrices would be a similarity transformation which preserves there the eigenvalues, and which I think should be as well valid with the same property for the infinite matrix. Note, that this is nothing else than reflecting the "Schroeder-function" for the function $f(x)$ , when its power series is shifted to its complex fixpoint. *($g(x)=f(x+t)-t$ where $t$ is the fixpoint)*

The result of this shifting is a formal power series with complex coefficients and complex eigenvalues, and -taking this in the view of Carleman-matrices- the according "similarity transformation" produces an infinite Carleman matrix with complex entries which is triangular and has complex eigenvalues.

A matrix-formula would look like this:
Denote the Carlemanmatrix for $f(x)$ by $F$ and the matrix performing a similarity-transform $P(t)$ and the remaining core-matrix $G$ which is the Carleman-matrix associated to function $g(x)$
$$ G = P(t) \cdot F \cdot P(t)^{-1}$$
where $P(t)$ and $G$ are triangular. Here the eigenvalues of $G$ should be equal to that of $F$, but are complex-valued if $b \gt \eta$ and thus the fixpoint $t$ is complex itself.

However, each ***truncation*** (from the upper-left edge of $F$) instead of the similarity-transformation gives a finitely-sized Vandermonde-style matrix, and this matrices have ***real*** eigenvalues, ***whose maximal value grows quadratically(?) with the truncation-size towards $\infty$ but not towards complex values***.
So increasing the truncation-size should thus never produce convergence towards the eigenvalues of $F$.

---

*(If we look at $f(x)$ for some $b$ in the range $1<b<\eta$ then we get a carleman-matrix which can be similarity-transformed by real-valued matrix-factors (representing function-conjugacy towards a real fixpoint) and whose triangular core-matrix has also real values and real eigenvalues).*

---

***Remark: I've not yet come at a formal and rigorous statement and/or analysis of this so far, so I've to give this as a hypothese, for which I've however much evidence.***